# How do I avoid ambiguity in functioning when I have inheritance and recurssion

Tags: python

I have this function:

```
class MiniMaxCompetition(MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithRandomWQuiescence):
def __init__(self, utility, my_color, no_more_time, w, treshold_quiet, reasonable_depth_value, b_quiescence):
    MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithRandomWQuiescence.__init__(self, utility, my_color, no_more_time, w, treshold_quiet, reasonable_depth_value)
    self.b_quiescence = b_quiescence

def quiescence_search(self, state, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player, utility_father):
    return MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithRandomWQuiescence.quiescence_search(self, state, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player, utility_father)

def search(self, state, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player, utility_father):
    """Start the MiniMax algorithm.

    :param state: The state to start from.
    :param depth: The maximum allowed depth for the algorithm.
    :param alpha: The alpha of the alpha-beta pruning.
    :param alpha: The beta of the alpha-beta pruning.
    :param maximizing_player: Whether this is a max node (True) or a min node (False).
    :return: A tuple: (The alpha-beta algorithm value, The move in case of max node or None in min mode)
    """

    if (self.b_quiescence):
        return MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithRandomWQuiescence.search(self, state, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player, utility_father)
    else:
        return MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithRandomW.search(self, state, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player)
```

when I run I get into second scenario of method search, and it calls:

```
class MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithRandomW(MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruning):
def __init__(self, utility, my_color, no_more_time, w):
    MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruning.__init__(self, utility, my_color, no_more_time)
    self.w = w

def search(self, state, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player):
    """Start the MiniMax algorithm.

    :param state: The state to start from.
    :param depth: The maximum allowed depth for the algorithm.
    :param alpha: The alpha of the alpha-beta pruning.
    :param alpha: The beta of the alpha-beta pruning.
    :param maximizing_player: Whether this is a max node (True) or a min node (False).
    :return: A tuple: (The alpha-beta algorithm value, The move in case of max node or None in min mode)
    """

    if (self.w == 1):
        return MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruning.search(self, state, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player)
    elif ((self.w < 1) and (self.w > 0)):
        if depth == 0 or self.no_more_time():
            return self.utility(state), None

        next_moves = state.legalMoves()
        if not next_moves:
            # This player has no moves. So the previous player is the winner.
            return INFINITY if state.currPlayer != self.my_color else -INFINITY, None

        num_moves_to_choose = int(len(next_moves) * self.w)
        random_idxs = random.sample(range(len(next_moves)), num_moves_to_choose)
        if maximizing_player:
            selected_move = next_moves[0]
            best_move_utility = -INFINITY
            for i in random_idxs:
                new_state = copy.deepcopy(state) 
                new_state.doMove(next_moves[i])                    
                minimax_value, _ = self.search(new_state, depth - 1, alpha, beta, False)
                alpha = max(alpha, minimax_value)
                if minimax_value > best_move_utility:
                    best_move_utility = minimax_value
                    selected_move = next_moves[i]
                if beta <= alpha or self.no_more_time():
                    break
            return alpha, selected_move
        else:
            for i in random_idxs:
                new_state = copy.deepcopy(state) 
                new_state.doMove(next_moves[i])                    
                beta = min(beta, self.search(new_state, depth - 1, alpha, beta, True)[0])
                if beta <= alpha or self.no_more_time():
                    break
            return beta, None
    else:
        print('Error w is wrong value - {}'.format(self.w))
```

However, when I try to run i get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 869, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Eli\workspace\HW2\amazons\utils.py", line 36, in function_wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Eli\workspace\HW2\amazons\MiniMaxCompetition.py", line 34, in search
    return MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithRandomW.search(self, state, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player)
  File "C:\Users\Eli\workspace\HW2\amazons\MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithRandomW.py", line 45, in search
    minimax_value, _ = self.search(new_state, depth - 1, alpha, beta, False)
TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'utility_father'
```

It seems when it tries to make the recursion it confuses between the method search. Why is this happening? How do I avoid it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to fix the indentation in your code

Comment: If you're calling the parent implementation, you need to supply it the parameters it needs - why is that a surprise?

Comment: what do you mean? when I call MiniMaxWithAlphaBetaPruningWithRandomW? I don't see where I don't supply the parameters, what I see is when I call myself (the recursive function in parent) for some reasom it asks me for the parameter in the son.

Comment: You've broken Liskov substitutability; the parent and child `search` methods take different parameters (and Python doesn't have overloading).

Comment: Exactly! what should I do about that?

Comment: ...make them have the same signature?

Comment: But I don't want to add an extra unnecessary parameter to the grandfather signature - can't something else be done?

Comment: You could maybe use `*args` or `**kwargs`?

Comment: Those extremely long class names aren't helping the readability of your code.

Answer (score 0):

About the only mitigation (given the conflicting desires expressed in the comments) is to use optional arguments to "ignore" the more specific child args.  It doesn't necessarily lead to terribly readable code:

```
class P:
  def foo(self,a,b,c,*args):
     # args is ignored
     ...

class C(P):
  def foo(self,a,b,c,d,*args):
     ...
     if something:
        return someone.foo(a,b,c)
     else:
        return someone.foo(a,b,c,d)
```

Note this can also be done with keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Making `utility_father` optional might be an option:

```
def search(self, state, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player, utility_father=None):
```